# ExtJS adding children to an empty async treenode

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I've noticed that in ExtJS (version 3) if you create an async treenode followed by a page refresh, the resulting node won't allow a child node to be moved / added into it. On attempting to drag and drop a node the text turns to italics without any further info being logged to the console, and the moved node moves back to its original position.

This seems a little strange due to the fact that if you create a new async node and then add a child *without* refreshing the page, the node is added without a problem.

On further inspection, it appears that on refreshing the page the resulting node config is showing: `loaded: false`, whereas this is `loaded: true` if you create the node and don't refresh the page.

**Is there any way to force an async treenode to load even if it doesn't have any children ?**

Thanks

Comment: an actual working example (http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_Forum_Help#Posting_a_working_showcase) would encourage answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with a similar problem where they can't drop children on an empty asynctreenode...

The workaround I've had to use is to append a dummy node to force the asynctreenode to load and subsequently remove the dummy after the asynctreenode has loaded. Slightly convoluted but prevents modification to the core.

Answer (score 0):

The key is a "leaf" parameter. You'll not be able to drop items if target node has leaf:true.
You can try to specify `leaf:false, loaded:true` for your leaf nodes. In this case the `loaded:true` is specified to not show arrow or plus sign beside leaf nodes.

Comment: The leaf parameter is set to false which is the conundrum. The only difference between this node and another node is the loaded:true. Explicitly setting this parameter seems to make no difference other than not showing the arrow. Hmm.